# Variable is not defined after several if and for statements using regex search function for parsing in Python

Tags: python, regex, list, parsing, for-loop

I'm parsing several text files in Python in order to find blocks of code that get repeated over and over again. The aim is to merge the similar blocks of codes of different files into another file.

Therefore, I need to scan the text file, find the block of interest by using a regex search and then storing the line where it begins and ends in the original text file. In the end, I can then write that block of code into another file, using the "begin and end lines" as a boundary.

The extract of code below is a part of this main code that I described, but the variable "layer_end" is not being defined. Any suggestions?

```
    with open(f_path, 'r') as gcode: # Opening each file separately
        for i, line in enumerate(gcode.readlines()): # Searching for the beginning of given layer
            if rgx_start.search(line):
                start_i = prev_start[cube_i]
                print(start_i)
                if i > start_i:
                    layer_start = i + 2
                    break
        for i, line in enumerate(gcode.readlines()):  # Searching for the end of given layer
            if rgx_end.search(line):
                if i > layer_start:
                    layer_end = i - 2
                    break
        for i, line in enumerate(gcode.readlines()):
            if i in range(layer_start, (layer_end + 1)):  # Writing the code of that given layer
                final_code.write(line)
        prev_start.append(layer_start)
        print(prev_start)
        prev_end.append(layer_end)
```

Comment: So what is your question exactly? Are you asking why your variable isn't defined if you don't enter the code that assigns it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readlines` can only be called once per open file. `start_i` never changes inside the for-loop and since the inner `if` is only true, if i is greater than some value, you can just start at this element.

```
with open(f_path, 'r') as gcode: # Opening each file separately
    lines = gcode.readlines()

start_i = prev_start[cube_i]
for i, line in enumerate(lines[start_i+1:]): # Searching for the beginning of given layer
    if rgx_start.search(line):
        layer_start = start_i + i + 3
        break
for i, line in enumerate(lines[layer_start+1:]):  # Searching for the end of given layer
    if rgx_end.search(line):
        layer_end = layer_start + i - 1
        break
final_code.write(lines[layer_start:layer_end + 1)
prev_start.append(layer_start)
print(prev_start)
prev_end.append(layer_end)
```